# How can i use a function in different files in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I'm trying to use a function, which is in a different component from `App.js`.
and I'm having the syntax error, I don't know what did I do wrong. I have a button in `App.js` and when I click on it, that function from another component that I've mentioned earlier should trigger.

**app.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import {shaking} from './components/Tree/Tree.js';

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        shaking();
        console.log("done !");
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Tree className='tree' />
                <Apples />
                <Basket />
                <br/>
                <button className="start-btn" onClick={this.handleClick}>Start !</button>
                <br/>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default App;
```

And this is my another **component**:

```
import React from 'react';
import TreeSvg from './Tree-svg/TreeSvg.js';
import './Tree.sass';

export  function shaking(){
    const tree = document.getElemenetsByClassName(".tree-img")[0];
    tree.classList.add("apply-shake");
    console.log('shaked!');
}

class Tree extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
    super();
        this.shaking = this.shaking.bind(this);
    }

    shaking() {
        this.setState({shaked:'1'});
        const tree = document.getElemenetByClassName(".tree-img");
        tree.classList.add("apply-shake");
        console.log('shaked!');
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="tree-img">
            <TreeSvg />
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default Tree;
```

Comment: Can you please share the complete error here. Also in the constructor, you can't set state like that.

Comment: ("TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function")
This is what i see after clicking on button

Comment: This is happening because your default export is the class. Try to export the function as default.

Comment: you mean i export tree component without default?

Comment: Yes, try to export your function as default as whenever we import a component, the export default is called.

Comment: well now i face another error : 
(document.getElemenetByClassName is not a function)

Comment: Check the spelling of getElementByClassName

Answer (score 0):

Make your Tree component like this

```
import React from 'react';
import TreeSvg from './Tree-svg/TreeSvg.js';
import './Tree.sass';

export  function shaking(){
    const tree = document.getElementsByClassName(".tree-img")[0];
    tree.classList.add("apply-shake");
    console.log('shaked!');
}



class Tree extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        shaked : ''
    }
shaking() {
    this.setState({shaked:'1'});
    const tree = document.getElementByClassName(".tree-img");
    tree.classList.add("apply-shake");
    console.log('shaked!');
    }
render(){
return(
    <div className="tree-img">
    <TreeSvg />
    </div>
 );
}
};


export default Tree;
```

Comment: can i target a component like this => const tree = document.getElementByClassName(".tree-img");

Answer (score 0):

You do have 2 syntax errors in your code. Both are located at the `Tree` component file.

1. At your exported function (Line 6): 
   `const tree = document.getElemenetsByClassName(".tree-img")[0];`
   replace `Elemenets` with `Elements`.
2. At the class method `shaking()` (Line 21):
   `const tree = document.getElemenetByClassName(".tree-img");` replace `Elemenet` with `Element`